# How can i add parameter to the given url which is dynamic in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, parameters, link-to

I have page having url

```
http://localhost:3000/athletes/list
```

When user search on this page it changes to something like

```
http://localhost:3000/athletes/list?first_name=sachin&last_name=tendulkar
```

Where `first_name` and `last_name` are the search parameters when user search.

I want a link which add the parameter view_type=something in url `for ex.`
For 1st URL

```
http://localhost:3000/athletes/list?view_type=something
```

For 2nd URL

```
http://localhost:3000/athletes/list?first_name=sachin&last_name=tendulkar&view_type=something
```

I have tried following

```
<%= link_to "Something ", :view_type => 'something' %>
```

But for both url it gives following  url

```
http://localhost:3000/athletes/list?view_type=something
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<%= link_to "Something ", params.merge(:view_type => 'something')  %>
```

Though above code works in most of the cases for some reason it is giving error for some url may be because i am using friendly_url `for ex.`

for url

```
http://localhost:3000/athlete/sachin_ramesh_tendulkar_1
```

giving me following wrong url

```
http://localhost:3000/athlete/1?view_type=something
```

To fixed this i am using `javascript` method as follows

```
function something(){
    var par =""
    var link =window.location.href
    if (link.indexOf('view_type=something') == -1)
        par = link.indexOf('?') != -1 ? "&view_type=something" : "?view_type=something"
    window.location.href = link+par
}
```

and rails code

```
<%= link_to "Something ", "javascript:void(0)", :onclick => "something();"  %>
```

Answer (score 1):

this might be useful as well (from the API)

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to#343-link-to-some-url-with-current-params